# gcc inline simd assembly error : short type movdqu instruction

Tags: c, x86, sse, inline-assembly, simd

I am studying SIMD(SSE) programing in Linux x64..
I want to assign one array short type to the other short array type var.
But executed result is wrong
here is my source. what is problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    short sArrayA[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    short sArrayB[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    __asm__ __volatile__(
       "movdqu %1, %%xmm0\n\t"
       "movdqu %%xmm0, %0"
       :"=g"(sArrayB)
       :"x"(sArrayA)
       :"%xmm0"
    );

    printf("sArrayB : %d, %d, %d\n", sArrayB[0], sArrayB[1], sArrayB[2] );
    return 0;
}
```

result is :

```
sArrayB : -13600, -24676, 32767
```

Comment: While experimenting with asm is interesting, using intrinsics (like Paul suggests) is almost certainly the better way to go.  But if you MUST use asm, change your `"x"` to `"m"`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: And  `"=g"` to `"=x"`, while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

Use intrinsics rather than messing around with inline asm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    short sArrayA[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    short sArrayB[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)sArrayA);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)sArrayB, v);

    printf("sArrayB : %d, %d, %d\n", sArrayB[0], sArrayB[1], sArrayB[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sArrayB : 1, 2, 3
```